# Which happens first: init or preDispatch?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I was reading the [answer to the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182759/zend-framework-what-are-the-differences-between-init-and-predispatch-functio) and the wording was a bit confusing. I shortened the sentences to focus on my question

> - First preDispatch() is called for instances of
>     Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract...
> - init() of the Zend_Controller_Action is called next...
> - The controller's preDispatch() method is called here...

Does that mean that in the **controller itself**, `init` code runs first before the `preDispatch` code?

There's a preDispatch that runs first but it's not for controller code, just for code that may exist in any outside plugins, correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`init` runs before `preDispatch`, `init` is short for initialisation (or initialization if you're American).

So it runs first to initialisation anything you might need later in the Controller

Answer (score 10):

Indeed, the init runs before preDispatch. A complete flow of events is visualized in this diagram: [image]

For me it was very useful to understand the complete Zend Framework frontcontroller structure.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `init()` method to your own action helper, which hooks into your controller `init()`, either way you can utilize the `init()` before `preDispatch()`.