# What's the difference between __construct() and init()

Tags: php, zend-framework

I was wondering what is the difference between `__construct()` and `init()` functions in a PHP application, more particularly in a Zend Framework application.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

init() is called by the constructor.

init() isn't defined in the specification of PHP, it's only a method available with the Zend Framework to help initialize without having to rewrite the constructor yourself.

---

**On the same topic :**

- [Zend Framework: What are the differences between init() and preDispatch() functions in controller objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182759/zend-framework-what-are-the-differences-between-init-and-predispatch-functio)

Comment: So... if I am to summarize... `init` is called by `__construct`? Or is it the case that `init` is called after `__construct`?

Comment: In case it matters now, but init() is not called by the constructor, its called by the service manager later, if it implements `InitializableInterface` - this is so you can construct the class with dependencies and options as a separate task to initialising it with data later

Answer (score 12):

[__construct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) is a php [magic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) method. It always exists and is called on object creation. init() is just a reguar method usually used in ZF..